# Expressjs: Can't set httpOnly cookies in Postman. Response cookies are not there in the postman cookies tab

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies

I'm setting an httpOnly cookie after login in a user with bcrypt.

```
router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    User.findOne({email: req.body.email}, function(err, user) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (user) {
            user.comparePassword(req.body.password, function(err, isMatch) {
                if (err) throw err;
                let token = jwt.sign({ id: user._id }, process.env.SECRET_KEY, {expiresIn: '24h'});
                res.cookie('token', token, {maxAge: 60*1000, httpOnly: true, secure: true})
                res.status(200).json(user)
            });
        } else {
            res.status(404).send("User not found!")
        }
    });
});
```

But the problem is that, after sending the request in postman, no cookie is saved in the `cookies` tab. I can see the user data returned in postman as response body, also there's the response header `Set-Cookie` with value `token=eyJhbGciO...19oUxXc; Max-Age=60; Path=/; Expires=Sun, 01 Aug 2021 17:49:39 GMT; HttpOnly; Secure`, I don't know what this header does.

But there's no cookie in the response `cookies` tab in postman. Before I've seen every time a cookie comes as a response, it also displays in the response `cookies` tab. [image: postman ss].

Answer (score 4):

Solved! I needed to set `secure=false` in development.

Comment: Where did you set that variable?

Comment: Here in the `user.comparePassword(...)` function:`res.cookie('token', token, {maxAge: 60*1000, httpOnly: true, secure: false})` and keeping it `false` until the project goes live.